# Fast partial matching with multi-component keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I have a big list of multi-component keys constructed of
poi data types with comparison operators defined:

```
typedef boost::tuple<int, char, unsigned long> Key;
```

These keys I want to match against fixed set patterns,
which consists of same components, but in particular
pattern some component could be omitted:

```
typedef boost::tuple<
    boost::optional<int>
    , boost::optional<char>
    , boost::optional<unsigned long> > Pattern;
```

boost::optional with value unset represents
asterisk, "match everything":

```
Key(1, 2, 3) match Pattern(1, 2, *)
Key(1, 2, 3) match Pattern(*, 2, 3)
```

And I want to perform matches faster than O(N) where
N is quantity of patterns.

I've started with custom comparison operator1 for patterns
to store them in sorted vector. Operator1 just sorts
asterisks after everything else. Then perform queries
with std::lower_bound with custom comparison operator2.
Operator2 omits unset key components during comparison. 
But I guess I cant get away with single sorted vector 
because if second component is * and I omit it there's
no guarantee that "slice" of third components are sorted
and I get something useful with std::lower_bound.

Comment: you'll want one index per 'shape' of search. building the indexes is expensive, but you could use an unordered_map to get average constant time on the searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the keys in some order. Make an index for each component, maintaining the same sort order.

Find the next item for each component using the index. If indices point to the same item you have a match. If not pick the component that points to the smallest item (in the sort order) and skip until you are at least at the largest item (std::lower_bound would do it).

This is the same algorithm for intersecting sorted lists.

The speed depends on how dense your data is. If you search for (*, *, true) and 95% of the data matches you are going to be O(N). If the data is sufficiently sparse this can be very fast.

Comment: It's a good idea to use multiple keys for each of your indices, and to try to organise them so that the set of *all prefixes of* these ordered key lists covers as many (unordered) sets of keys as possible.  E.g. suppose there are 4 fields, A, B, C and D, then you could make 4 indices: ABCD, BCD, CDA, DBA.  Now any query that specifies all 4, or any 3 of the 4 fields can be answered with a single binary search, and the only kinds of queries that require a join of the kind you describe are those that specify only AC or only AD.  (You could of course add 2 more indexes to handle this.)

Comment: I match one Key against set of Patterns at a time. Say, I have K(1,2,3) and [P(1,2,4),P(1,2,*)]. What compound index should I use? As mentioned by Sorin I should make index for each component, query each index for both component value and * and intersect resulting (six) lists.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You are correct, but I would put it more as an optimization. The performance is determined by how fast you can jump through the lists you are intersecting, which is determined by how different the entries are. If you make compound keys you dramatically increase the entropy of those fields (so faster), but it can also take more space (especially if you try to cover different combinations of fields). Unless you benchmark and notice that you need to be faster, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @Sorin: I'm confused; if you represent an index simply as an array of pointers into (i.e., integer positions within) the original data records, then an index on any number of keys takes the same amount of space.  Building an index on k keys takes (up to) k times as long as building one on 1 key, sure, but you only do this once.  Also I'm not sure what you mean by "entropy" here.

Comment: For n specified fields, your algorithm takes time proportional to n times the size of the union of the matches for each field, plus n binary searches.  If you have the right n-key index available, mine takes time proportional to the size of the *intersection*, plus a single binary search.  If you don't have a single index for all n keys, but you have i < n multikey indices, some of whose prefixes can be combined to make all n keys, then you can use your i-way join, but on just i < n instead of n indexes -- this will still be cheaper.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: As long as asterisks could be everythere there's no "right" n-key index. If you build index on first two of three componets there would be 4 binary searches: you must query for (1, 2), (1, asterisk ), (asterisk, 2), (*, *) to get all matches. Then two searches for third component and that's still total 6.

Comment: @DmitryTeslenko: I don't understand your example -- what exactly are the indexes that you have built, and what is the query we are now trying to answer with them?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I have patterns [P(1,2,4),P(1,2,*),P( *, *,3)]. I want to find out what patterns match key K(1,2,3). What n-key index should I use to query for my K with single binary search?

Comment: @DmitryTeslenko: Then I've misunderstood what you're trying to do -- nearly always, the *query* is a pattern that can contain `*`s, and you want to find the subset of keys that match this query pattern; my algorithm is superior for this situation.  (You made it clear that you are instead looking for the set of patterns that match a given query *key* in your first comment here, which I didn't pay much attention to as it wasn't addressed to me; but it's not clear from your original question.)  Of course if you are doing a one-time all vs. all, you can still use my approach.

Comment: @DmitryTeslenko: Another confusing point is that Sorin's post says "This is the same algorithm for intersecting sorted lists" -- this also describes *my* algorithm, but AFAICT *doesn't* describe a solution to your problem, where the query is a key and the result is a set of patterns.